# GRPC .net framework 4.6.2 problems connecting server hosted in AWS

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dns, grpc

)

We are trying to develop a **.net** application in wpf with which is consuming grpc services which are deployed on **AWS.**
The connection is done through **GRPC**.

Our code is as follows:

```
public static GrpcManagerFactory GetGrpcManagerFactory(ConnectionConfiguration configuration, string connectionString, DataAccess.Util.Enumerations.LogLevel clientLogLevel, bool errorMode)
{
    Logger logger = new Logger(connectionString, clientLogLevel);          

    var caRootsPem = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"..", "cacert.pem"));
    var caRootsKey = new KeyCertificatePair(caRootsPem, File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"..", "AmazonRootCA1.key")));
    ChannelCredentials channelCredentials = new SslCredentials(caRootsPem, caRootsKey, VerifyPeerContext);

    var channel = new Channel(configuration.GrpcHost, configuration.GrpcPort, channelCredentials, new List<ChannelOption> {  });

    channel.ConnectAsync(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10).ToUniversalTime());

    var provider = DataAccess.DataProvider.Grpc.GrpcFactory.GetGrpcFactory(channel, configuration, logger.LogManager.LogController);
    var manFactory = new GrpcManagerFactory(provider, channel, connectionString, configuration.InterfaceRetries, clientLogLevel);
    manFactory.ErrorMode = errorMode;
    return manFactory;
}
```

When we try to either do a heartbeat or grpc request (.protos), we get either a DNS error, or that all connections fail....

Any idea?

This is our ConnectionConfiguration

```
public ConnectionConfiguration ConnectionConfiguration
        {
#if DEBUG
            get
            {
                
                    return new ConnectionConfiguration
                        {
                            ClientId = _client != null ? _client.ClientId : 0,
                            InterfaceRetries = _clientPreferences != null ? (_clientPreferences.Depot != null ? _clientPreferences.Depot.InterfaceRetries : 1) : 1,
                            WenAccessTokenUrl = "token",
                            WenClientId = "..",
                            WenClientSecret = "..",
                            RealWebServices = true,
                            GrpcHost = "..",
                            GrpcPort = ..,
                            GrpcChannelCredentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure
                        };
                }

}
```

We tried to self signed our request but we get the same error.

ERROR:

*DNS resolution failed for service: (AWS host)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally we got it working.

.Net Framework version 4.6.2

In the following way

```
            List<ChannelOption> channelOptions = new List<ChannelOption>()
            {
                new ChannelOption("grpc.ssl_target_name_override", "services.hosted.in.the.cloud.com"),
            };

            var channelCreds = new SslCredentials(File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @".\xxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem"));
            
            var channel = new Channel("services.hosted.in.the.cloud.com", 443, channelCreds, channelOptions);
```

and at the System Environment Variables..

```
    GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER: native
```

with this settings it worked for us, connecting the grpc client to the services deployed on aws cloud